AntD DatePicker and date-fns configuring
As you know rc-picker is a part of AntD DatePicker. We want to use AntD DatePicker with date-fns library and using guide from official source we need to import 'generateConfig' file from rc-picker/lib/generate/dateFns.
We have rc-picker like dependency of AntD dependency in node_modules. How we can use this file without extra installing rc-picker
